# How to group all possible integers into three buckets

Tags: math, switch-statement

I want to be able to evenly, reproducibly, and predictably switch an inputted integer value into one of three cases.  If it was two cases, it would be obvious.

Pseudo code:

```
switch (integer) {
    if even:
       something;
       break;
    if odd:
       something else;
       break;
}
```

I want to do the same thing but for three cases, and I'm kind of stumped as to how I can do that.  Probably because I'm not really very good at math.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about dividing by 3?

```
switch (x % 3) { // compute the remainder 
  case 0: // 0, 3, 6, 9, ...
    something;
    break;
  case 1: // 1, 4, 7, 10, ...
    something;
    break;
  case 2: // 2, 5, 8, 11, ...
    something;
    break;
}
```

You need to watch out for the sign - some languages will compute `(-5) % 3` as `-2` instead of `1`, so you might need to use `abs(x) % 3` instead of `x % 3` or add `case` statements:

```
switch (x % 3) { // compute the remainder 
  case 0: // -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, ...
    something;
    break;
  case 1: // 1, 4, 7, 10, ...
  case -2: // ... -5, -2
    something;
    break;
  case 2: // 2, 5, 8, 11, ...
  case -1: // ... -4, -1
    something;
    break;
}
```

See [remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) and [modulus operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

PS in Common Lisp you would use [`mod`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mod_r.htm):

```
(ecase (mod x 3)
  (0 ...)
  (1 ...)
  (2 ...))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be ... or num % 3 , ... ? Also for C / C++, num needs to be unsigned, as a negative number % 3 could result in 0, -1, or -2.